Exterior derivative of Chern-Simons form
I am following the notation of Mathematical Gauge Theory by Hamilton. This question comes from Exercise 5.15.16.
Let $P\to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle over a manifold $M$ and let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be a scalar product on $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $A$ be a connection 1-form on $P$ and its curvature $F=\mathrm{d}A+\frac{1}{2}[A,A]$. Define the Chern-Simons form to be $\alpha=\langle A,F\rangle-\frac{1}{6}\langle A,[A,A]\rangle$. I want to show that $\mathrm{d}\alpha=\langle F,F\rangle$, but I am struggling. There are some identities which will be helpful: for $\omega\in\Omega^k(P,\mathfrak{g})$, $\eta\in\Omega^l(P,\mathfrak{g})$, $\phi\in\Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$, $$\mathrm{d}\langle\omega,\eta\rangle=\langle\mathrm{d}\omega,\eta\rangle+(-1)^k\langle\omega,\mathrm{d}\eta\rangle,\tag{1}$$ $$\langle[\phi,\omega],\eta\rangle=-(-1)^k\langle\omega,[\phi,\eta]\rangle,\tag{2}$$ $$\mathrm{d}[\omega,\eta]=[\mathrm{d}\omega,\eta]+(-1)^k[\omega,\mathrm{d}\eta],\tag{3}$$ $$[\omega,\eta]=-(-1)^{kl}[\eta,\omega],\tag{4}$$
My attempt: simply compute \begin{align} \mathrm{d}\alpha&=\langle\mathrm{d}A,F\rangle-\langle A,\mathrm{d}F\rangle-\frac{1}{6}\langle\mathrm{d}A,[A,A]\rangle+\frac{1}{6}\langle A,\mathrm{d}[A,A]\rangle \tag{using (1)} \\
&=\langle\mathrm{d}A,F\rangle-\frac{1}{3}\langle A,\mathrm{d}[A,A]\rangle-\frac{1}{6}\langle\mathrm{d}A,[A,A]\rangle \tag{def. of $F$} \\
&=\langle\mathrm{d}A,F\rangle-\frac{2}{3}\langle A,[\mathrm{d}A,A]\rangle-\frac{1}{6}\langle\mathrm{d}A,[A,A]\rangle \tag{using (3)} \\
&=\langle\mathrm{d}A,F\rangle+\frac{2}{3}\langle [A,\mathrm{d}A],A\rangle-\frac{1}{6}\langle\mathrm{d}A,[A,A]\rangle \tag{using (4)} \\
&=\langle\mathrm{d}A,F\rangle-\frac{5}{6}\langle \mathrm{d}A,[A,A]\rangle. \tag{using (2)} \\
\end{align}
This simplification doesn't seem to be correct. Can anyone spot the error or offer any hints?

Use: (1) $d\langle A,[A,A]\rangle=3\langle dA,[A,A]\rangle$, (2) Bianchi identity for $dF$, (3) $\langle [A,A],[A,A]\rangle =0$. There seems to be errors in the second line of your computation.

Taken directly from proposition 4.4.6 in my bachelor's thesis.
Since $d\langle\omega,\eta\rangle=\langle d\omega,\eta\rangle +(-1)^{|\omega|}\langle\omega,d\eta\rangle$, \begin{align*}
    d\alpha=\langle dA,F\rangle -\langle A,dF\rangle -\frac{1}{6}\langle dA,[A,A]\rangle+\frac{1}{6}\langle A,d[A,A]\rangle=\\
    \langle dA,F\rangle +\langle A,[A,F]\rangle-\frac{1}{6}\langle dA,[A,A]\rangle+\frac{1}{6}\langle A,2[dA,A]\rangle
\end{align*}
Where we used the Bianchi identity $dF+[A,F]=0\implies dF=-[A,F]$ and $d[A,A]=[dA,A]-[A,dA]=2[dA,A]$. Then, $$\langle A,[dA,A]\rangle=-\langle A,[A,dA]\rangle=-\langle[A,A],dA\rangle$$
since $$\langle[\tau,\omega],\eta\rangle=-(-1)^{|\omega|}\langle\omega,[\tau,\eta]\rangle$$
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    d\alpha=\langle dA,F\rangle+\langle A,[A,F]\rangle -\frac{1}{2}\langle dA,[A,A]\rangle
\end{equation*}
Next, we have
\begin{equation*}
     \langle F,F\rangle=\langle dA+\frac{1}{2}[A,A],F\rangle=\langle dA,F\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\langle [A,A],F\rangle
\end{equation*}
So it suffices to show that $\langle A,[A,F]\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle dA,[A,A]\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle[A,A],F\rangle$. Now observe that
\begin{align*}
    \langle A,[A,F]\rangle=\langle[A,A],F\rangle=\langle [A,A],dA\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle[A,A],[A,A]\rangle=\\
    \langle [A,A],dA\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle A,[A,[A,A]]\rangle
\end{align*}
Since $[A,[A,A]]=0$, it follows that $\langle A,[A,F]\rangle=\langle [A,A],dA\rangle$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
    \langle A,[A,F]\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle dA,[A,A]\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle dA,[A,A]\rangle=\\
    \frac{1}{2}\langle[A,A],dA\rangle +\frac{1}{4}\langle [A,A],[A,A]\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle [A,A],dA+\frac{1}{2}[A,A]\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle [A,A],F\rangle
\end{align*}
Therefore, $d\alpha=\langle F,F\rangle$.

what is the reason for $[A,[A,A]]=0$? I can't see it straight away. I see $\langle [A,A],[A,A]\rangle=0$ from applying $(2)$ in two different ways.

Hint: use the graded Jacobi identity. But your argument is probably simpler anyway.
